# How to change the first occurrence of 'True' in a row to false in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to change the first instance of `True` to `False` in my DataFrame dependent on row:

```
              A       B      C  
   Number
   1          True   True   True   
   2          False  True   True  
   3          False  False  True   

              A       B      C  
   Number
   1          False  True   True   
   2          False  False  True  
   3          False  False  False
```

Every time I try using the `for index, row in target_df.iterrows():` line it ends up never finding any 'True' when I look through the row.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the cumulative sum of the Boolean values (False corresponds to 0; True to 1) for each row, along with [`DataFrame.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
>>> condition = df.cumsum(axis=1) == 1
>>> df.mask(condition, False)
       a      b      c
0  False   True   True
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
```

> `df.mask(self, cond, other=nan)`
>
> Return an object of same shape as self and whose corresponding entries
>   are from self where cond is False and otherwise are from other.

In this case, `condition` is False everywhere except the points at which you want to switch `True` -> `False`:

```
>>> condition
       a      b      c
0   True  False  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False   True
```

One other option would be to use NumPy:

```
>>> row, col = np.where(df.cumsum(axis=1) == 1)
>>> df.values[row, col] = False
>>> df
       a      b      c
0  False   True   True
1  False  False   True
2  False  False  False
```